# How do I convert number with ordinal suffix to Number in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let string = "13th"

string = Number(string)
```

I expect it to return 13 instead I get NaN please how do I go about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

```js
let string = "13th";

string = parseInt(string);
console.log(string);
```